# How to add lines of codes to another public function of a class?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-store-apps

Is this possible?

The dilemma in my class (lets call it parent class), is calling a class that is having an event that is always called every tick (or every second, because it is a timer class)

What I want to do is that the in the Parent Class is to override the event of the timer class so that I can add lines of codes when the event execute.

or Is it possible to just pass lines of codes to the timer class.

Comment: Choose a language or explain how they both apply.

Answer (score 0):

Create the timer class as an abstract class, this should allow you to inherit and override methods of the timer class